# React Component Not Rendering after Webpacker refactoring

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, webpacker

I am trying to shift from react-rails to webpacker for my Rails 5.1.3 app - and am using the webpacker-react gem. Everything seems to be loading fine (no errors), however the React component itself won't render.

in application.js

```
import WebpackerReact from 'webpacker-react'
import UserSchedule from 'components/userschedule'
console.log('First test')
```

in my erb view:

```
<%= react_component 'UserSchedule', render(template: 'appts/user-sched.json.jbuilder') %>
```

Inside the UserSchedule.jsx I have this code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

console.log('User schedule file test')

class UserSchedule extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('User schedule inside render')
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <p>TEST THAT THIS WORKS</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The console logging works on everything except for inside the render.

```
User schedule outside test
First test
```

So I know the jsx file is loading. And inside the rendered elements the proper html tag is showing up:

```
<div data-react-class="UserSchedule" data-react-props="&quot;{\&quot;appts\&quot;:[{\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;Isobel ...
```

So what am I doing wrong? Anyone else do this shift before from the react-rails to webpacker with the webpacker-react gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your js file

```
WebpackerReact.setup({UserSchedule})
```

and this too

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

console.log('User schedule file test')

class UserSchedule extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('User schedule inside render')
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <p>TEST THAT THIS WORKS</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}    
export default UserSchedule; //add this
```